# Hover without mouse in Atom

Tags: atom-editor

I'm a heavy vim user (at least until very recently). I'm wondering if there's a way to do everything hover does (regardless of which extensions I'm using) using hotkeys. So, for example, if I wanted to bind `Space + t` to hover over where my cursor is, what would I write? Or is this not possible?

Obviously, I'm using Atom.